# Background process without a window

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I need to prepare a program which runs in the background without a window or anything on the taskbar. You may compare this to the idea of a program which runs in the background and sends a signal every once in a while to keep the computer from sleeping. 
So here are the two ideas that I have on my mind

```
1) Creating a windows Service
2) Spawning a thread and exiting main
```

Please let me know how viable these are, particularly the second one, and what other possibilities do we have at our disposal.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: A service can't interact with the desktop.  Starting a thread and exiting main() is pointless, you already have a perfectly good thread and it will terminate your program.  If you want a program that doesn't have a window then just don't create a window, easy peasy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just link your application for `windows` subsystem, not `console`

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to run a background process then go with the service approach. You'll be able to configure it to run even when nobody is logged in and it won't be intrusive to the user.